# Nextjs FE with Express BE to make API calls to a payment gateway

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, express, next.js

I need to make an API from my node server and share the data with my Nextjs App. The node server is in a folder called `server/index.js` in my Nextjs apps root folder.

`npm run dev` is defined as `nodemon server/index.js` in my package.json.

This is my Next js page which calls the node server:

```
// const __DEV__ = document.domain === 'localhost'

const RoomBilling = (props) => {

    const { fromDate, toDate, numberOfGuest, numberOfRooms } = props;



    const loadScript = (src) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = src;
            script.onload = () => {
                resolve(true);
            }
            script.onerror = () => {
                resolve(false)
            }
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        })
    }


    const displayRazorPay = async () => {

        const loadingScript = await loadScript('https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js');
        if(!loadingScript){
            //Show toast error
            return;
        }


        //This is where I make a request to my node server to return certain data defined in the next file
        const data = await fetch('/razorpay',{method: 'POST'}).then((t) => t.json())




        const options = {
            key: document.domain === 'localhost' ? "DEV_KEY" : 'PROD_KEY', // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
            amount: data.amount, 
            currency: data.currency,
            name: "BNB",
            description: "Bed and Breakfast",
            image: "./../public/dino.svg",
            order_id: data.id,
            handler: function (response){
                alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
                alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
                alert(response.razorpay_signature)
            },
            prefill: {
                //get user data from info modal
                "name": "Gaurav Kumar",
                "email": "gaurav.kumar@example.com",
                "contact": "9999999999"
            },
            notes: {
                
                "address": "Razorpay Corporate Office"
            },
            theme: {
                "color": "#F37254"
            }
        };
        const paymentObj = new Razorpay(options);
        paymentObj.open();
    }
    
    return(
        <>
        <h2 className="mt-4">Room 3</h2>
            <div className="w-full mt-6 py-4 px-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg flex flex-col flex-grow">
                <div className="">
                    <p className="text-2xl">₹<span>1999</span><span className="text-base"> /night</span></p>
                    <p className="mt-2"><span>{fromDate}</span> to <span>{toDate}</span></p>
                    <p className="mt-6">₹<span>1999</span> x <span>{numberOfRooms}</span><span className="float-right">₹<span>3998</span></span></p>
                    <p className="mt-2">Extra Bedding<span className="float-right">₹<span>750</span></span></p>
                    <p className="mt-4 font-bold">Total<span className="float-right">₹<span>4748</span></span></p>
                </div>
                <div className="btn-action text-center my-8">
                    <button className="btn-primary ml-2" onClick={displayRazorPay}> Book now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default RoomBilling;
```

My server/index.js file:

```
const next = require('next')
let RazorPay = require('razorpay');
const shortid = require('shortid');


const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();



const razorpay = new RazorPay({
                        key_id: 'TEST_KEY',
                        key_secret: 'TEST_SECRET',
                      });

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();


   

    server.get("*", (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

  //   server.get('/rooms', (req, res) => {
  //     const actualPage = '/rooms'
  //     const queryParams = { from: req.params.from, to: req.params.to, guest: req.params.guest, rooms: req.params.rooms } 
  //     app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
  // })

    server.post('/razorpay ', async (req, res) => {
      const payment_capture = 1;
      const amount = 299 * 100; // convert to paisa
      const currency = 'INR';
      const receipt = shortid.generate();

      const options = {
        amount,
        currency,
        receipt,
        payment_capture
      }
      const response = await razorpay.orders.create(options)
      console.log("response");
      res.json({
        id: response.id,
        currency: response.currency,
        amount: response.amount
      });
    })

    server.listen(PORT, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`> Ready on ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Whenever I make this request to my BE, I get a **404** ** not found ** error. The API call never reaches my express server.

Also, for routing to the **/rooms** page I use Nextjs `<Link/>` component. Should I be rendering the page from my server itself? I have commented out the **/rooms** app render in my server/index.js file. It does not render the page if I remove the `<Link/>` routing.

Comment: Not entirely sure if I follow correctly, but it seems the fetch url should be `http://localhost:3000/razorpay`. But to confirm, you are running both next.js and your server right? I would recommend you look into https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction because it seems a much more elegant solution than what you currently have.

Comment: Yes, I'm running both on ```http:localhost:3000```. I needed a node server since I need to integrate a payment gateway.  Also, can I use nextjs for routing and express explicitly for the payment related code ?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot run 2 applications on the same port? Anyway if you use a tool like Postman to test your API does it work then?

Comment: Yes the APIs work fine in Postman